# Test for bad reCAPTCHA sitekey with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

Is there a way to programmatically test (with javascript) whether or not a Google reCAPTCHA sitekey is valid?  For example, when an invalid sitekey is provided to reCAPTCHA, the following error message is displayed within the reCAPTCHA widget:

> ERROR for site owner: Invalid site key

I'd like to test for this condition in code.

Comment: This seems like something you'd find in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro) for using reCAPTCHA.

Comment: You'd think so but the documentation is very basic.

Comment: Hm. Have you tried making a page with the tag and an invalid sitekey, and watching the dev console?

Comment: @jack - Yes.  I've monitored the dev console and even dug into the grecaptcha object.

Comment: I'd love to know how to improve my question, from whoever downvoted me.  Is this not a community?  Downvote with no comment?  Odd behavior.

Comment: I did some research and I couldn't find a way on how to parse this error.
The problem is that the captcha loads inside an iframe with a different domain. If you try to load the captcha data and check that data for errors, then you'll have loading errors due to CORS.
There is a way loading the captcha outside the iframe, but it's for v1, not for v2. 
I think the only way to do this check, is by using a server side script to fetch, parse and check the captcha result for such errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Google doesn't give any option for developers to verify a site key, and it cannot be done programmatically with Javascript as recaptcha is an iframe and the frames html code cannot be accessed client-side.

The only possible solution would be to implement some kind of web scraping tool to take a screen capture of the ReCaptcha widget and return a result if the sitekey is valid or not.

A tool that might help can be found [here](http://scraping.pro/uipath-robotic-process-automation-software/)

Comment: Not sure why you voted me down for this answer considering it's the only way to implement what you want.